# Catch undefined index in array and create it

Tags: php, arrays

```
<h1><?php echo $GLOBALS['translate']['About'] ?></h1>
Notice: Undefined index: About in page.html on line 19
```

Is it possible to "catch" an undefined index so that I can create it (database lookup) & return it from my function and then perform echo ?

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to check if a value has been assigned is to use the isset method:

```
if(!isset($GLOBALS['translate']['About'])) {
    $GLOBALS['translate']['About'] = "Assigned";
}
echo $GLOBALS['translate']['About'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if this particular index exists before you access it. See the manual on `isset()`. It's a bit clumsy as you have to write the variable name twice.

```
if( isset($GLOBALS['translate']['About']) )
    echo $GLOBALS['translate']['About'];
```

You might also consider changing the `error_reporting` value for your production environment.

Answer (score 1):

that wouldn't be the right thing to do. i would put effort into building the array properly. otherwise you can end up with 1000 db requests per page.

also, you should check the array before output, and maybe put a default value there:

```
<h1><?php echo isset($GLOBALS['translate']['About'])?$GLOBALS['translate']['About']:'default'; ?></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use isset to determine if the index is defined and then, if it isn't, you can assign it a value.

```
if(!isset($GLOBALS['translate']['About'])) {
    $GLOBALS['translate']['About'] = 'foo';
    }
echo "<h1>" .  $GLOBALS['translate']['About'] . "</h1>";
```

Comment: this is a very sloppy post: a spurious `)`, missing `;`, missing open/close tags...

Comment: Whooops... that was indeed pretty bad. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
if ( !isset($GLOBALS['translate']['About']) )
{
    $GLOBALS['translate']['About'] = get_the_data('About');
}
echo $GLOBALS['translate']['About'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your custom error handler if you want to catch *Undefined index*

```
set_error_handler('exceptions_error_handler');

function exceptions_error_handler($severity, $message, $filename, $lineno) {
  if (error_reporting() == 0) {
    return;
  }
  if (error_reporting() & $severity) {
    throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $severity, $filename, $lineno);
  }
}
try{
}catch(Exception $e){
 echo "message error";
}
```